# How to use fragmentAdapter to recieve different fragments in different situations

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I have an Activity in which im trying to implement a viewpager.
the problem lies in the fact that each situation can have different amount of fragments and screens to show.

basically in my current project the object can contain 4 data items each corresponds with a different fragment.

e.g if for instance i have data items 1,3 and 4 while 2 is missing the swipe need to go to from one to 3 then 4 and backward swipe needs to go 4,3,1

so i wrote the getCount method to make sure how many i have and i use a map to go through the list and make sure they are mapped correctly.
However the app itself makes mistakes and shows different fragments than what is required.
I wonder what am i missing and is there a better approach?

```
public DemoFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, MYObject currentObject) {
        super(fm);
        set_currentObject(currentObject);
        createItemConvertionMap();
    }

@Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count=0;
        if (_currentObject.get_type1()!=null&&_currentObject.get_type1().isEmpty()==false)
        {
            count++;
        }
        if (_currentObject.get_type2()!=null&&
                _currentObject.get_type2().isEmpty()==false)
        {
            count++;
        }
        if (_currentObject.get_type3()!=null&&
                _currentObject.get_type3().isEmpty()==false)
        {
            count++;
        }
        if (_currentObject.get_type4()!=null&&_currentObject.get_type4().isEmpty()==false)
        {
            count++;
        }
        Log.d(MyApplication.LOG_TAG,"fragment adaprter - count:\n"+count);

        return count;
    }

public void createItemConvertionMap() {
        _convertionMap=new HashMap<>();
        int i=0;
        if (_currentObject.get_type1()!=null&&_currentObject.get_type1().isEmpty()==false)
        {
            _convertionMap.put(i, TYPE1);
            i++;
        }
        if (_currentObject.get_type2()!=null&&
                _currentObject.get_type2().isEmpty()==false)
        {
            _convertionMap.put(i, TYPE2);
            i++;
        }
        if (_currentObject.get_type3()!=null&&
                _currentObject.get_type3().isEmpty()==false)
        {
            _convertionMap.put(i, TYPE3);
            i++;
        }
        if (_currentObject.get_type4()!=null&&_currentObject.get_type4().isEmpty()==false)
        {
            _convertionMap.put(i, TYPE4);
            i++;
        }
    }

@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment=new FragmentType1();//default
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        int fragmentItem=get_convertionMap().get(i);
        Log.d(MyApplication.LOG_TAG,"fragment adaprter - item key requested:"+i +" item convertion is:"+fragmentItem);
        switch (fragmentItem) {
        case TYPE1:
            Log.d(MyApplication.LOG_TAG,"fragment adaprter - returning TYPE1 fragment");
            fragment=new FragmenType1();
            break;
        case TYPE2:
            Log.d(MyApplication.LOG_TAG,"fragment adaprter - returning TYPE2fragment");
            fragment=new FragmentType2();
            break;
        case TYPE3:
            Log.d(MyApplication.LOG_TAG,"fragment adaprter - returning TYPE3 fragment");
            fragment=new FragmentType3();
            break;

        case TYPE4:
            Log.d(MyApplication.LOG_TAG,"fragment adaprter - returning TYPE 4 fragment");
            fragment=new FragmentType4();   
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(MyApplication.LOG_TAG,"fragment adaprter - an error with returend converted item returning default fragment");
            break;
        }
        // TODO finish object bundle
        args.putInt(MyActivity.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

the log after activation first object shows fine it has 2 data items and both apaer correctlly second one isnt working well it has 3 data items but when the pagar goes through them it goes TYPE1,TYPE4,TYPE4 instead of TYPE1,TYPE2,TYPE4:

```
03-17 15:05:16.482: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:16.482: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:16.492: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:16.492: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:16.494: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - item key requested:0 item convertion is:0
03-17 15:05:16.494: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - returning TYPE1 fragment
03-17 15:05:16.494: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - item key requested:1 item convertion is:3
03-17 15:05:16.494: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - returning TYPE4 fragment
03-17 15:05:16.494: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:16.494: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:16.550: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:16.550: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:16.588: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:16.588: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:16.588: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:16.588: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:16.589: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:16.589: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.133: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.133: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.134: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.134: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.134: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.134: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.160: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.160: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.177: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.177: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.194: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.194: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.195: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.195: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.197: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.197: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.210: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.210: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.210: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.210: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.212: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.212: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.245: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.245: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.245: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.245: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.246: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.246: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.273: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.273: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.273: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.273: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.273: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.273: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.274: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.274: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.274: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.274: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.279: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.279: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.294: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.294: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.311: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.311: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.326: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.326: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.343: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.343: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.360: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.360: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.376: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.376: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.393: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.393: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.410: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.410: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.426: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.426: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.443: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.443: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.459: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.459: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.476: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.476: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.493: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.493: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.509: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.509: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.527: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.527: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.543: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.543: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.560: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.560: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.577: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.577: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.593: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.593: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.610: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.610: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.627: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.627: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.643: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.643: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.660: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.660: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.677: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.677: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.694: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.694: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.710: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.710: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.727: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.727: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.744: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.744: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.760: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.760: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.777: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.777: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.794: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.794: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.810: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.810: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.828: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.828: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.845: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.845: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.860: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.860: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:43.861: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:43.861: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.112: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.112: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.112: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.112: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.112: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.112: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.147: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.147: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.164: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.164: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.180: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.180: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.180: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.180: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.182: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.182: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.198: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.198: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.199: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.199: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.200: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.200: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.214: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.214: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.214: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.214: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.216: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.216: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.243: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.243: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.243: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.243: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.244: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.244: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.251: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.251: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.251: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.251: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.252: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.252: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.264: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.264: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.264: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.264: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.265: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.265: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.280: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.280: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.281: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.281: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.281: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.281: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.297: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.297: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.298: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.298: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.298: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.298: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.314: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.314: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.314: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.314: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.316: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.316: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.331: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.331: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.331: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.331: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.332: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.332: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.348: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.348: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.349: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.349: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.350: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.350: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.366: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.367: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.367: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.382: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.382: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.399: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.399: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.416: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.416: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.432: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.432: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.448: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.448: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.465: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.465: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.482: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.482: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.498: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.498: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.515: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.515: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.532: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.532: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.549: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.549: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.566: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.566: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.582: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.582: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.599: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.599: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.616: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.616: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.632: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.632: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.649: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.649: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.666: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.666: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.682: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.682: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.699: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.699: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.716: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.716: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.732: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.732: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.749: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.749: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.766: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.766: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.783: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.783: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.799: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.799: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.816: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.816: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.833: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.833: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.850: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.850: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.867: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.867: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.883: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.883: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.899: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.899: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.916: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.916: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.933: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.933: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.949: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.949: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:45.966: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:45.966: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:51.150: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.150: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:51.150: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.150: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:51.150: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.150: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:51.150: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.150: D/GABI(955): 2
03-17 15:05:51.165: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.165: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:51.170: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.170: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:51.170: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.170: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:51.186: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.186: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:51.186: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.186: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:51.258: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.258: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:51.272: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.272: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:51.272: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.272: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:51.273: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:51.273: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:52.996: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:52.996: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:52.996: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:52.996: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:52.996: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:52.996: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.017: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.017: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.034: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.034: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.051: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.051: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.051: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.051: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.053: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.053: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.067: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.067: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.067: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.067: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.069: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.069: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.084: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.084: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.084: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.084: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.086: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.086: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.100: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.100: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.100: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.100: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.101: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.101: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.106: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.106: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.106: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.106: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.106: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.106: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.117: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.117: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.134: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.134: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.151: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.151: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.168: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.168: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.184: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.184: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.201: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.201: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.218: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.218: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.234: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.234: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.251: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.251: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.268: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.268: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.284: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.284: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.301: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.301: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.318: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.318: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.335: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.335: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.351: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.351: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.368: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.368: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.385: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.385: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.401: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.401: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.418: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.418: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.435: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.435: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.452: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.452: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.468: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.468: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.485: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.485: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.485: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - item key requested:2 item convertion is:3
03-17 15:05:53.485: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - returning TYPE4 fragment
03-17 15:05:53.485: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.485: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.490: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.490: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.490: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.490: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.491: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.491: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.976: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.976: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.976: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.976: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:53.976: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:53.976: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.003: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.003: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.019: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.019: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.020: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.020: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.022: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.022: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.036: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.036: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.036: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.036: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.038: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.038: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.053: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.053: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.053: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.053: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.054: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.054: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.069: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.069: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.069: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.069: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.070: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.070: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.075: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.075: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.075: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.075: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.075: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.075: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.086: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.086: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.103: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.103: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.120: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.120: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.136: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.136: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.153: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.153: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.170: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.170: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.187: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.187: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.203: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.203: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.220: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.220: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.237: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.237: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.254: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.254: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.270: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.270: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.287: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.287: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.303: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.303: D/GABI(955): 3
03-17 15:05:54.321: D/GABI(955): fragment adaprter - count:
03-17 15:05:54.321: D/GABI(955): 3
```

Comment: Why do you have 4 types in your object?
Currently your object can be 4 types at the same time. That's really confusing.

Comment: its not really 4 types i swapped the real content. basically the object can contain 4 data items each corresponds with a different fragment. if for instance i have data items 1,3 and 4 while 2 is missing the swipe need to go to from one to 3 then 4 and backward swipe needs to go 4,3,1

Comment: Can you explain your exact problem what's wrong with the fragments. So which fragments will be loaded and what do you expect. Please add the console output of your debugging. Can you trace your object too that we can see the values of it? Note that if you think that the adapter will only load 1 fragment you're wrong. Default offscreenpage is 1 and can't be lower.

Comment: @beeb added log and explanation

Comment: So your object will be changed dynamically and update it's viewpageradapter so fragments will be added dynamically right? So always if you change your object, you have to update your internal convertion map because this is your mapping where you decide which fragment will be shown. Debug the code where you recreate your map and check it's values. Also debug the values of your object which is a reference in your adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i know whats your problem. As i said the viewpagers offscreenpage default and minimum is 1. So the first fragment is type 1. The second fragment is type 4. Now your object will be updated and type 2 is added. But the fragments 1 (type 1) and 2 (type 4) are already loaded and in your viewpagers cache.

**Your map before the update:**

index 0 = type 1

index 1 = type 4

**Your map after the update:**

index 0 = type 1

index 1 = type 2 <- this one is new

index 2 = type 4

**What you currently see at your screen:**

index 0 = type 1

index 1 = type 4 <- this one is not updated (it should be 2)

index 2 = type 4

But the new type (type 2) won't be updated because it's already loaded and cached at index 1. The adapter will create the fragment of index 2 correctly which is type 4.

Comment: on object change i use recreate() method for  the entire activity that contain the viewpager. should that not cover that scenario?

Comment: you are correct i think, i added the following line to the method prior calling recreate - viewPager.setAdapter(null) ; it clears the adapter which is then recreated in the oncreateview method of the activity. i find it illogical that there is chache saved when i restart the entire activity but cant argue with results :/ ty